# Plotting surface - enhacing the output

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def figure():
    fig = plt.figure()
    axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    x = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.1)
    y = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.1)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    f = lambda x, y: 1/np.log(y - (x-1)**0.5)
    axes.plot_wireframe(x, y, f(x, y))
    plt.show()

figure()
```

How can I "zoom" in to the figure (make it appear larger)?
Is there a way to make the figure look smoother when using `axes.plot_surface` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, I would prefer [`np.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) over `np.arange`.

Many of the function values in your range are complex. Those values cannot be displayed. Here I use [`axes.set_xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) and [`axes.set_ylim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) to zoom into the real part of your function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def figure():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    x = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 100)
    y = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 100)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    f = lambda x, y: 1/np.log(y - (x-1)**0.5)
    axes.plot_wireframe(x, y, f(x, y))
    axes.set_xlim(1,1.5)
    axes.set_ylim(0,1.5)

figure()
```

[image: plot]